# odesk API POST job with Python

Tags: python, api, odesk

I'm trying to post a job to an odesk account using their API.  Unfortunately, I'm having trouble doing so.

I was able to get authenticated and GET my jobs, but when I tried POSTing a job, it returns a 400 error.

Here is response body.

```
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
Exception at POST https://www.odesk.com/api/hr/v2/jobs.json
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 21:38:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
X-Odesk-Error-Code: 4
X-Odesk-Error-Message: Parameter job_data is missing or invalid
Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 21:38:08 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
```

I'm also using python-odesk.
I followed this to the T, and I got the above error.
https://github.com/odesk/python-odesk/blob/master/examples/get_create_update_jobs.py

There was a discussion on this:
https://www.odesk.com/community/node/19676
But I don't think it's solved.

I'm even trying to send through Postman and I get a:
"Not all required params were filled"

I've tried the following packets to send to odesk.
Assume XXXXXX is a valid buyer_team__reference.

```
    data = {
            'buyer_team__reference': XXXXXX,
            'title': 'Test job from API',
            'job_type': 'hourly',
            'description': 'this is test job, please do not apply to it',
            'visibility': 'invite-only',
            'category': 'Web Development',
            'subcategory': 'Web Programming',
            'budget': 10,
            'duration': 7,
    }
```

or

```
    data = {
            'job_data': {
                    'buyer_team__reference': XXXXXX,
                    'title': 'Test job from API',
                    'job_type': 'hourly',
                    'description': 'this is test job, please do not apply to it',
                    'visibility': 'invite-only',
                    'category': 'Web Development',
                    'subcategory': 'Web Programming',
                    'budget': 10,
                    'duration': 7,
            }
    }
```

Note: I've tried many variations of this similar packet, but with no success.

If someone has experience in odesk API in any language, any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying [python-odesk](https://github.com/odesk/python-odesk), i gave up and used mechanize instead to automate the job posting into oDesk

Do a `pip install mechanize`

```
import mechanize,cookielib
# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# Want debugging messages?
#br.set_debug_http(True)
#br.set_debug_redirects(True)
#br.set_debug_responses(True)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# Open odesk site
r = br.open('https://www.odesk.com/login.php')
form = br.forms().next()  # the login form is unnamed...
print form.action
form['login'] = 'yourlogin'
form['password'] = 'yourpassword'
br.form = form
br.submit()

print br.geturl()
#your form data goes here
r = br.open(br.geturl() + 'new/')
print br.geturl()
br.select_form(name="jobsPost")  # the form is unnamed...
br.find_control(name="category").value = ['Writing & Translation']
br.find_control(name="subcategory").value = ['35']
br.form['title'] = 'Filling up a profile'
br.form['description'] = 'Require assistance in filing up our profile'
br.find_control(name="job_type").value = ['Fixed']
br.form['job_budget'] = '10'
br.form['job_finish_date'] = '10-14-2012'
br.find_control(name="visibility").value = ['private']
br.submit()

print br.geturl()
```